# Bug with radiobutton - tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I use Tkinter for make a GUI. I have a window with 2 radiobutton ('Yes' and 'No'), but when I select one, it don't run the script :

```
root = Tk()

Button(root, text='TEST', command=root.quit).pack()

root.mainloop()

master = Tk()
v = IntVar()

Radiobutton(master, text='Yes', variable=v, value=0).pack()
Radiobutton(master, text='No', variable=v, value=1).pack()
Button(master, text='Exit', command=master.quit).pack()

master.mainloop()

print(v.get())

if v.get() == 0:
    testy = Tk()
    Label(testy, text='Bad').pack()
    testy.mainloop()

else:
    testn = Tk()
    Label(testn, text='Bad').pack()
    testn.mainloop()
```

If I don't have the first window, it works but with it, it don't.

Somebody know how to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

1. You have initiated several `Tk()` systems, but there should be only one.
2. If you want to get a new window then use `Toplevel()`
3. No code is executed after `mainloop()` except for events. The code continues to "flow" after `mainloop` only after closing the windows.

So here is your code with fixes:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

Button(root, text='TEST', command=root.quit).pack()

master = Toplevel()
v = IntVar()

def check_radio():
    print(v.get())

    if v.get() == 0:
        Label(Toplevel(), text='Bad').pack()
    else:
        Label(Toplevel(), text='Good').pack()


Radiobutton(master, text='Yes', variable=v, value=0, command=check_radio).pack()
Radiobutton(master, text='No', variable=v, value=1, command=check_radio).pack()
Button(master, text='Exit', command=master.quit).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Check carefully, I changed the parents of widgets and other changes.

Comment: Ok thanks and if I want to get back the infos of radiobutton, how I need to do ?

Comment: As you can see in the code, I added another arg to the creation of the radiobutton: command=check_radio, which invoke check_radio on pressing the radiobutton

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate of [tkinter radiobutton not updating variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40900792/tkinter-radiobutton-not-updating-variable/44035410#44035410), but seeing as this question was asked first the answer may make more sense here.

---

Make sure you are assigning a master to the IntVar like `self.rbv=tk.IntVar(master) #or 'root' or whatever you are using)`:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

class My_GUI:

    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master=master
        master.title("TestRadio")

        self.rbv=tk.IntVar(master)#<--- HERE! notice I specify 'master'
        self.rb1=tk.Radiobutton(master,text="Radio1",variable=self.rbv,value=0,indicatoron=False,command=self.onRadioChange)
        self.rb1.pack(side='left')
        self.rb2=tk.Radiobutton(master,text="Radio2",variable=self.rbv,value=1,indicatoron=False,command=self.onRadioChange)
        self.rb2.pack(side='left')
        self.rb3=tk.Radiobutton(master,text="Radio3",variable=self.rbv,value=2,indicatoron=False,command=self.onRadioChange)
        self.rb3.pack(side='left')

    def onRadioChange(self,event=None):
        print self.rbv.get()

root=tk.Tk()
gui=My_GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

try running that, click the different buttons (they are radiobuttons but with indicatoron=False) and you will see it prints correctly changed values!