# tkinter radiobutton not updating variable

Tags: python, tkinter

--UPDATE: 
I changed

```
variable=self.optionVal.get()
```

to

```
variable=self.optionVal
```

But nothing changed.Also I wonder why it automatically call self.selected while compiling?

----Original:

I'm trying to get familiar with radiobutton, but I don't think I understand how radiobutton works. Here's a brief code for demonstration:

```
     self.optionVal = StringVar()
     for text, val in OPTIONS:
         print(text,val)
         radioButton = Radiobutton(self,
                                   text=text,
                                   value=val,
                                   variable=self.optionVal.get(),
                                   command = self.selected())
        radioButton.pack(anchor=W) 

     def selected(self):
        print("this option is :"+self.optionVal.get())

In my opinion this should work like once I choose certain button, and it prints out "this option is *the value*", however now what it does is once compiled, it prints out everything, and the self.optionVal.get() is blankspace, as if value wasn't set to that variable.

I wonder what happens to my code,
Many thanks in advance.
```

Comment: You need to pass the **actual variable** as the ``variable`` parameter, not the result of calling ``.get()`` on the variable.

Comment: @jasonharper I tried but it's still not passing

Answer (score 15):

AHA! I beleive I've figured it out. I had the exact same issue. make sure you are assigning a master to the IntVar like `self.rbv=tk.IntVar(master) #or 'root' or whatever you are using)`:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

class My_GUI:

    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master=master
        master.title("TestRadio")

        self.rbv=tk.IntVar(master)#<--- HERE! notice I specify 'master'
        self.rb1=tk.Radiobutton(master,text="Radio1",variable=self.rbv,value=0,indicatoron=False,command=self.onRadioChange)
        self.rb1.pack(side='left')
        self.rb2=tk.Radiobutton(master,text="Radio2",variable=self.rbv,value=1,indicatoron=False,command=self.onRadioChange)
        self.rb2.pack(side='left')
        self.rb3=tk.Radiobutton(master,text="Radio3",variable=self.rbv,value=2,indicatoron=False,command=self.onRadioChange)
        self.rb3.pack(side='left')

    def onRadioChange(self,event=None):
        print self.rbv.get()

root=tk.Tk()
gui=My_GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

try running that, click the different buttons (they are radiobuttons but with indicatoron=False) and you will see it prints correctly changed values!

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was missing. Though this isn't the answer to OP's question but for people coming here from the Google search "radiobutton not working" this could be a real saviour. Need to mention, that this only needs to be done when you have more than one `Tk()` instances.

Comment: Thanks! Was hard to find when you picked it up for the first time and probably last time :p

Answer (score 2):

You're very close. Just take out the `.get()` from `self.optionVal.get()`. The `Radiobutton` constructor is expecting a traced variable, you're giving it the result of evaluating that variable instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

1. Remove the `.get()` from the `variable=self.optionVal` argument in the constructor the button. You want to pass the variable, not the evaluated value of the variable; and
2. Remove the parenthesis from `command=self.selected()` and use `command=self.selected` instead. The parenthesis says "call this function now and use the return value as the callback". Instead, you want to use the function itself as the callback. To better understand this, you need to study closures: a function can return a function (and, if that was the case, that would be used as your callback).

**EDIT:** A quick reminder, also: Python is not compiled, but interpreted. Your callback is being called while the script is being *interpreted*.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying those for me! I followed 1 and 2, while now it only print out "this option is :"when I click it, it still doesn't give the corresponding self.optionVal.get()  but keeps giving back blankspace. Do you have any other idea? I was thinking it doesn't update self.optionVal at all

Comment: What is `val` and `text` in your code? Paste the whole code.

Answer (score 0):

```
def view(interface):
    choice = interface.v.get()
    if choice == 0:
        output = "0"
    elif choice == 1:
        output = "1"
    elif choice == 2:
        output = "2"
    elif choice == 3:
        output = "3"
    else:
        output = "Invalid selection"

    return tk.messagebox.showinfo('PythonGuides', f'You Selected {output}.')    


class Start:
    
        def __init__(self):
            self.root = tk.Tk()
            self.root.geometry('500x500')
            self.root.resizable(False, False)
            self.root.title('find out the degree of severity')
            self.v = tk.IntVar()
            dolori_ossa = {"nessun dolore": 0,
                              "dolori articolari": 1,
                              "frattura composta": 2,
                              "frattura scomposta": 3}
            for (txt, val) in dolori_ossa.items():
                    tk.Radiobutton(self.root,
                                   text=txt,
                                   variable=self.v,
                                   value=val,
                                   command=lambda:view(self)
                                   
                                   ).pack()
```

Comment: the variable is not validated when I click the button, it always has value 0 or the value I initialize it with

Comment: the same problem aswell without the loop

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Users find it difficult to understand code only answers with no explanation. Please add some description explaining what is does and how it solves the problem or add comments in the source code at appropriate places.